# PYQT5 designer, where did the maximize button go?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, designer

Everytime I make a GUI using PYQT5 designer the window has a minimize and close button but there is no Maximize/reset size button. Please see [image: this image] to see what I mean.

Where did it go? How do I add that button in?

Comment: Click on the `WindowMinimizeButtonHint` button or press `Ctrl + R`

Comment: Where is WindowMinimizeButtonHint  button located?

Comment: Next to the `WindowCloseButtonHint` button

Comment: Ok so where are those two buttons located? 
Also pressing ctrl + R just gives me the preview of the GUI.

Comment: In the preview of the GUI, do you see the button that was shaken?

Comment: No, there is no button shaking. Could you maybe upload a picture showing what you mean?